# How to stretch long table to new page in two column IEEE format?

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I have 60 rows and 12 columns with plenty of text data inside the table.I am using IEEEtran format.I want to place my table in whole page with continue to next page. Tried many libraries but didn't work for me. My code is given below.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] % filler text
    \begin{table*}
     \caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{10}{C}c@{}}
    \toprule
    labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer & dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ 
    \midrule
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
    \lipsum[2-15] % more filler text
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Any news? If no one answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs, longtable}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] % filler text
\onecolumn
    \begin{longtable}{lccccccccccc}
    \hline
    labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer & dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ 
    \hline
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
    \hline
    \end{longtable}
\twocolumn
    \lipsum[2-15] % more filler text
    \end{document}
```

Go from a normal table to a `longtable` environment and switch to single column manually `;-)`.

This gives:

[image]

Comment: ...It moves the table to the next page but when i increase the text inside columns then the size deteriorates as you can see here https://ibb.co/XYqp5rD

Comment: @Case Msee Because it does not know when to break lines. You have to break lines yourself. Moreover when you are inserting such a long number, this environment will treat that as a single number and displays it on a single line. Hence,the issue.

Comment: Nevertheless, you cannot fit more text in a page that exceeds limits of the page itself ;)

Comment: @Raaja...Thank you..My table has text data rather than numeric. Above was an example. Anyways the question is how to make table stretch to next page despite of larger text data.even with page break?

Comment: @CaseMsee, see another answer. Change article setup from two columns to one column and back always introduce  white space before and after long table those changes.

Answer (score 3):

Changing from two columns to one and back always start new page. Consequently using them usually introduce a lot of empty space at changing document formatting. Better is (to my opinion) manually split table in two (approximately equal) parts and inserts them successive into document as `table*`.

With use of the package `stfloats` is possible to put first part of table to the bottom of page (by use of the placement option `[b]` and second part to the top of the next page by the placement option `[t]` .

To make tables parts captions consistent, i.e. with the same figure number, use in the second table part before `\caption` the  command \ContinuedFloatt`defined in the`caption` package.

Beside this I recommend to use `S` column type (defined in `sinuntx` package) for coulns with numbers and for table environment use a `tabularx` by which is possible to prescribe beside table also column width. For the later is in the following MWE defined new command:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
```

for use in columns' headers:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text
    \begin{table*}[b]

    \centering
    \caption{My huge table}
\label{tab:hugetable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l *{10}{S[table-format=3.0]} c}
    \toprule
labels  
    & \mcx{airplane}    & \mcx{automobile}  & \mcx{bird}    & \mcx{cat}     & \mcx{deer} 
    & \mcx{dog}         & \mcx{frog}        & \mcx{horse}   & \mcx{ship}    & \mcx{truck} 
    & accuracy \\
    \midrule
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{12}{>{\footnotesize\itshape}r}{Continue on the next page}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}%
%
    \begin{table*}[t]
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption{My huge table (cont.)}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l *{10}{S[table-format=3.0]} c}
    \toprule
labels
    & \mcx{airplane}    & \mcx{automobile}  & \mcx{bird}    & \mcx{cat}     & \mcx{deer}
    & \mcx{dog}         & \mcx{frog}        & \mcx{horse}   & \mcx{ship}    & \mcx{truck}
    & accuracy \\
    \midrule
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\
    airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\
    automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\
    bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\
    cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\
    deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\
    \addlinespace
    dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\
    frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\
    horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\
    ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\
    truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum % more filler text
\end{document}
```

[image]